# Are there any icons for folders that fit in with gnome shell?

Tags: gnome, icons, 14.10

I want to give some folders different icons but I don't know where to get any from. I also want them to fit in with the default gnome shell theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your default path the system and program icons are stored in is `/usr/share/app-install/icons`. I would look there first for some suitable icons.